# Quarantine or add exclusion for malicious items?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, quarantine

I am having so many problems with my laptop. I have 8 malicious items detected and 4445 non malware items detected. Is it better to quarantine or add exclusion? I am not sure what add exclusion means.

Answer (score 2):

**Quarantine:** This means that you want your anti-virus software to isolate a malicious or potentially malicious item so that it can't harm your machine.

**Add Exclusion:** This means that even though your anti-virus thinks an item might be malicious or potentially malicious, you know that it isn't, and so you want your anti-virus to leave it alone and ignore it in the future.  If you choose this options for items that actually *are* malware, you're setting them loose on your machine to infect you as designed.

The option you want to choose is **quarantine**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option you would really want would be to re-install your computer (assuming you have a backup and a system restore disk).  That is the for sure way to get rid of malware.  However, I realize this is a frustrating process that many are not willing to go through.  In that case, Xander's advice is right.  Do NOT add exclusion, because that tells your antivirus software to ignore it.  You want to **quarantine** it, which isolates it as Xander says.

Answer (score -1):

***quarantine:*** This means place of isolation in which the malware would go so that it would not conflict with your computer.

***Add Exclusion***: This is not a good option. This means you have an idea of what the program that is begin detected and you want your anti-virus to leave it alone and ignore it in the future.

I would deferentially recommend"
***Quarantine***
.